# Altering speed of podcast playback on iOS 11.4.1

Tags: iphone

How do I alter playback speed on podcasts when no speed adjuster is shown? The previous x1 was a solution but this is no longer apparent.

Comment: In what application?  In Overcast, for example, you slide the player right, snd the speed control slides in from the left.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you're talking about the default Podcasts app, this still has a **1x** option located at below-left of the screen (just below the volume slider on the **main page of the episode** you're listening to).

Tapping on the **1x** option will cycle the options from **1x** to **1 1/2x** to **2x** to **1/2x** and back to **1x**.